# What does the shem adnus mean?

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

*Shulchan Aruch*, *Orach Chayim* 5:1, in my own (slightly loose) translation:

> One shall intend, in benedictions, the meaning of the words. When he mentions the name [of God, viz [the tetragrammaton](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetragrammaton)], he shall intend the meaning of its pronunciation as the *adnus* name, that He is master of all (שהוא אדון הכל), and he shall intend the meaning of its spelling as the *havaya* name, that He was and is and will be.

What does the *adnus* name, "that he is master of all", mean exactly? Some possibilities I can think of:

- Everyone must obey him.
- He controls every occurrence.
- He controls every creation.
- He created every creation.

Is it any of those? Perhaps something else?